# how can I create "Sliding Page" effect in asp.net web Application?

Tags: asp.net, slide

Looking to implement a solution on a web application but don't know if it is possible. If clicked the menu would take you to the full page with slide(Left to right / right to left). slide looks like iPhone Application.

Doe's anyone know of a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in JQuery effect Slide:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide

You can then slide in a panel which is preloaded or loaded through Ajax.